# Error when connecting to web3 and metamask

Tags: web3js, metamask

I use this code to connect ui with smart contract

```
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
      if (window.ethereum) {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        try {
          // Request account access if needed
          await window.ethereum.enable();
          currentAddress = web3js.eth.accounts[0]
          // Acccounts now exposed
          return web3;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
      // Legacy dapp browsers...
      else if (window.web3) {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = window.web3;
        console.log('Injected web3 detected.');
        return web3;
      }
      // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
      else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/abikeygoeshere');
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
        return web3;
      }
    });
```

but in my console i get this error

```
exchange.js:41 Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

this is in line 41

```
await window.ethereum.enable();
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
```

To:

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
```

Comment: now i get even more errors

Comment: List them here so we can inspect. Errors are something daily in this job, so get used to them :)

Comment: these are the errors im getting now
Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined
    at Object.InvalidResponse (inpage.js:1)
    at a.send (inpage.js:1)
    at w.e [as getBalance] (inpage.js:1)
    at exchange.js:43
InvalidResponse @ inpage.js:1
a.send @ inpage.js:1
e @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ exchange.js:43

Comment: Start with debugging your provider and web3. Are you sure you initiated your infura application correctly? DId you place your infura api key correctly at this row: const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/abikeygoeshere');

Comment: the error came from those 2 lines: let contract = web3.eth.getBalance('0xE462CbEE0cd420f6c199B0194B1D8D93Fb5e7720');
  //document.getElementById('agiContractBalance').value =contract;
  console.log(contract);